# CSS: what is causing this gap?

Tags: css

At [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/vm-home.html), around viewport width 870px, there is a gap that appears underneath each `.program-image img`:

[image]

How do I ensure each `.program-image img` is the height of each `.program`, or each `.program` is the height of each `.program-image img`?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: .program-image{padding-bottom:0;}

Comment: put some padding to .program-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the image height is dependant on its width, a gap is created because of this rule. To avoid this, I commonly add the image as a background image of a div, setting the background-size to cover (which makes the image cover the entire div).

First, remove the image tag and place the background image within the program-image div.

```
<div class="program">
   <div class="program-image" style="background-image:url('http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/program-pregnancy.jpg');">
        ...
```

Then I would go ahead to add the following css:

```
.program-image {
    height: 90px; // Or whatever height needed
    width: 45.23809523%;
    float: left;
    max-height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This sets the height of the div as it will not take into account the height dimension of the image.

To make sure the image doesn't overflow over the program element. Add the following:

```
.program {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Below is an example of how it looks (Second program is of how it currently is, example excludes background-position:center apologies).

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tag is `inline-block` element so you always need to define `vertical-align` for it. else make it block.

```
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

or use this

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
height: 100%;
```

or

```
min-height: 100%;
```

on the image selector.