# Resizing an using CSS is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Hi I am trying to achieve the desired look:

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mhM7.png)

However, when the text is longer or the screen is resized it can lead to this:

[How it looks with more text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAN53.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent hours trying to get this to work...Responsive is easy enough as it will appear under the text not side by side but the desktop preview is just killing me!

The HTML:

```
<div class="container-combo white">
        <div class="row-2col-equal-ignore image-combo">
                <div class="column">
                <div class="content">
                <h2>Located at the heart of our community to serve our community</h2>
                <img src="images/bkg-swirl.png" alt="swirl divider" class="swirl">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                <p>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                <img src="images/bedroom-combo.jpg" class="combo-img">
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The SCSS/CSS:

```
.image-combo {

.column {
margin-bottom: -5px;

    .content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 705px;
        padding-top: 61px;
        padding: 61px 10px 10px;

        h2 {
            color: $dark-grey;
            font-size: 34px;
            font-family: $minion;
            line-height: 40px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none;
            padding-bottom: 32px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: 24px;
            text-align: left;
            padding-bottom: 32px;
        }

        .swirl {
            float: none;
            max-width: 456px;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 1px;
        }
    }

    .flip {
        padding-right: 120px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    .combo-img {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 426px;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the image ratio there's no easy solution to the problem of having the text side by side with the image and cover all the possible situations. Having the text below the image if it occupies more than expected is an option? If so you have to float the image to the right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993595/css-what-is-causing-this-gap/42995821#42995821

Comment: I would set it as a background image set to `cover`, then revert to a standard `img` at the point where responsiveness kicks in to collapse these elements below each other.

Comment: After having a look over the suggested and trying a few things out I have reached the following...

The example image linked initially needs to be able to change to many different images therefore would be easier as an img tag rather than a background.

This said I am thinking using an earlier breakpoint to swap the image under the text to avoid the gap would be the easier and possible more correct of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I can't imagine how that would be easier - but to be fair, I don't know your intended methodology, so maybe in your use case it is. In my mind, simply updating a `background-image` property should be far easier than switching through embedded `img` tags either through javascript or styles hooked into `@media queries`, inserting multiple image tags into the page for this reason will increase load time and server requests and may just bloat the code unnecessarily. Either way, hope you find a fitting solution.

Comment: The images would be pulled in form Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress to change the image, the only styling used would make them float where needed, the sizing, 1 media query to switch to the mobile/tablet view window 2 queries at the most and then styling to remove the float so it just sits under the text in a block. Does any of that process seem unnecessary, I'm new to coding is all and I am trying to learn :D

Comment: You can still use background image when using advanced custom fields on wordpress using inline css styling. So for example <div style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('img'); ?>"></div>. Make sure the the acf field is giving the image link and not the actual image. You then would need to feed the other image to be used by javascript. Would you like an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `background-image` and `background-size: cover` like this it will work

```css
.image-combo {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 705px;
  padding-top: 61px;
  padding: 61px 10px 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: $dark-grey;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: $minion;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

.swirl {
  float: none;
  max-width: 456px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
}

.flip {
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
.column.img {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people/10/);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-combo white">
  <div class="row-2col-equal-ignore image-combo">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Located at the heart of our community to serve our community</h2>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x20" alt="swirl divider" class="swirl">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        <p>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this works, floats now have no impact therefore I cannot alternate where the image sits without changing the HTML. However it is coded in the HTML a set way so on mobile the image sits below the text.

Comment: @DanielVickers You can remove `flexbox` code from my answer. I used it only to make the text/image stay side by side. What my code show is how it can be done, you just need to make sure the right column height equals the left. This can be tricky and you might want to change it all to `flexbox`. Post a link to a fiddle (or codepen) with the full code and I'll have a look

Comment: I answered this by just adding width:auto to the image and a max-height. I then added overflow hidden to the container and will use srcset to select portions of the image.

I have accepted your answer as this is the way to do it if you do not need to float your objects.